# Sidebar Affects my page responsiveness and Something causes an overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

[HTML Code](https://github.com/Marrockx/personal-blog-website/blob/main/index.html)

I made some changes to CSS code so that my sidebar can  be fixed to the left, however even if I add margin-left to main content, it still extends beyond the view width

I want the page to be responsive with sidebar fixed to left and doesn't cover the main content while maintaining responsiveness

```css
/** @format */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap");
* {
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  /* max-width: 1000px; */
}

.content-wrap {
  /* .header-container, */
  /* .sidebar-container,
.main-content-wrap, */
  /* .footer-wrap  */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem 2.4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: repeat(8, min-max(200px, 1fr));
  /* grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 20rem); */
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd hd hd " "sd sd main main main " "sd sd nl nl nl " "ft ft ft ft ft ";
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* HEADER */

.header-container {
  grid-area: hd;
  background-color: #7c6447;
  height: 3.72rem;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.05rem 2rem 1rem #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0.05rem 2rem 0.01rem #000000;
  z-index: 5;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.nav-bar {
  padding: 20px 36px;
  background-color: #7c6447;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-bar a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #ece2d5;
  color: #763200;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.site-logo {
  color: #ece2d5;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.site-logo h1 {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border: 4px solid #ece2d5;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 300px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #1d1409;
  background: #ece2d5;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-btn .search-input {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #ece2d5;
  border: none;
  color: #1d1409;
}


/* FIXED SIDEBAR */

.sidebar-container {
  grid-area: sd;
  background-color: #ece2d5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 220px;
  left: 0;
  /* height: 200vh; */
}

.left-sidebar {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 20px #9b9b9b;
  color: #1d1409;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  transition: linear 2s;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.action-button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.24em;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 4px solid #1d1409;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #1d1409;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.action-button:hover {
  background-color: #763200;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #763200;
}

.social-media-menu {
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.social-links {
  text-decoration-style: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.social-links:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-media-menu .fa {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}

.social-media-menu .fa:hover {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


/* MAIN CONTENT */

.main-content-wrap {
  grid-area: main;
  margin-left: 284px;
}

.showcase {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.showcase-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -10;
  position: static;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.showcase-heading {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 20px #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-family: "Indie Flower", cursive;
}
.posts-navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.posts-navigation a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1.12rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.posts-navigation .all-posts:hover {
  color: #7c6447;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.posts-navigation .fa {
  margin-left: 0.4rem;
}

.posts-navigation .latest {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7c6447;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.latest-posts-wrap {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-gap: 2rem; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.post-card {
  width: 200px;
  /* border: 4px solid #000000; */
}

.card-image {
  height: 240px;
  width: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.more-btn {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.first-selected-post {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}

.first-selected-post:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.selected-posts-theme {
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.card-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, min-max(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 3rem 2rem;
}

.first-selected-post:first-child .selected-posts-theme {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* .post-card {
} */

.post-card:first-child {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.post-card:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 2;
}

.post-card:last-child {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.back-to-top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 0.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1d1409;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 3.6rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  bottom: 60rem;
  left: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 0 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.back-to-top .link {
  /* position: fixed;
  position: sticky;
  pointer-events: all; */
  /* top: calc(180vh - 0rem); */
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  background-color: #1d1409;
  color: #ece2d5;
}


/* Smooth scrolling IF user doesn't have a preference due to motion sensitivities */


/* @media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
} */


/* NEWSLETTER */

.newsletter-signup {
  grid-area: nl;
  background-color: #ece2d5;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.newsletter-heading {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #1d1409;
  letter-spacing: 0.16rem;
}

.newsletter-tagline {
  flex-grow: 2;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #7c6447;
  /* text-transform: capitalize; */
}

.newsletter-input {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background: #1d1409;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.newsletter-input input:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.newsletter-input>input {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.username,
.user-email,
.newsletter-form-submit {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #7c6447;
}

.newsletter-form-submit {
  background: #7c6447;
  color: #ece2d5;
  margin-top: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.newsletter-form-submit:hover {
  background: #763200;
  color: #1d1409;
}


/* FOOTER */

.footer-wrap {
  grid-area: ft;
  background: #000000;
  color: #efe;
  padding: 1rem 2.4rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .newsletter-input {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 893px) {
  .header-container {
    height: 8rem;
  }
  .header-content {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
  }
  .first-selected-post {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .selected-posts-theme {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .first-selected-post:first-child .selected-posts-theme {
    margin-top: 4rem;
  }
  .username,
  .user-email {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .newsletter-form-submit {
    width: 260px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  /* .showcase-image {
    max-width: 80%;
  } */
}


/* MOBILE DESIGN */

@media (max-width: 820px) {
  .header-content {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .header-container {
    height: 12rem;
  }
  .sidebar-container {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-content-wrap {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .content-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .showcase-heading{
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- @format -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Minimalist Decór</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newsletter.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="header-container">
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <header class="header-content" id="header">
        <!-- NAVIGATION-  -->
        <div class="nav-bar-wrap">
          <nav class="nav-bar">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="">about</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="site-logo">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350&w=494" alt="logo-icon" /> 
          <h1>minimalist decór</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="search-btn">
          <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="search here..." />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>

    <!-- FIXED SIDEBAR -->
    <div class="sidebar-container container">
      <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <div class="subscribe-button">
          <a href="#subscribe"><button type="menu" class="action-button">subscribe</button></a
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-media-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="social-links"
                                    ><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i
                                ></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="social-links"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i
                                ></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="social-links"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i
                                ></a>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        minimalist decór
      </aside>
    </div>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="main-content-wrap">
      <main class="main-content">
        <!-- SHOWCASE -->
        <section class="showcase">
          <img src="ihttps://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="A couch portraying minimalist decor" class="showcase-image" />
          <!-- <img src="images/blob1.webp" /> -->
          <h2 class="showcase-heading">
            Helping you to navigate through your aesthetics with a minimalism touch!
          </h2>
        </section>
        <div class="blog-posts container">
          <nav>
            <div class="posts-navigation">
              <!-- add arrow icons to all posts -->
              <div class="latest"><a href="#">latest posts</a></div>
              <div class="all-posts">
                <a href="#">all posts<i
                                            class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        ></i
                                    ></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div class="latest-posts-wrap">
            <div class="first-selected-post">
              <div class="card-wrap cardf-wrap">
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="images/throw-pillow.jpg" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            <a href="first-post.html" class="link">read more</a>
                                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            <a href="second-post.html" class="link">read more</a>
                                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            read more
                                        </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="selected-posts-theme">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea totam nemo dolore eius deserunt aut aperiam amet voluptatem doloremque iste eos officiis minima, delectus,
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="first-selected-post">
              <div class="selected-posts-theme">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea totam nemo dolore eius deserunt aut aperiam amet voluptatem doloremque iste eos officiis minima, delectus,
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-wrap">
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            read more
                                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            read more
                                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="post-card">
                  <div class="card-image-wrap">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7005461/pexels-photo-7005461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="some" class="card-image" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="action-button more-btn">
                                            read more
                                        </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="back-to-top"><a href="#header" class="link"
                            ><i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a
                    ></span>
      </main>
    </div>

    <!-- NEWSLETTER -->
    <div class="newsletter-signup">
      <h4 class="newsletter-heading">subscribe to our newsletter</h4>
      <span class="newsletter-tagline">for tips to spice up your minimalism lifestyle and add a fine touch
                    to it regularly.
                    <!-- TODO: down arrow --></span
                >
                <form class="newsletter-input">
                    <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="name" />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        class="user-email"
                        placeholder="enter email address"
                    />
                    <button type="submit" class="newsletter-form-submit">submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <div class="footer-wrap">
                <footer class="footer-content">
                    <small
                        >made with love by
                        <a href="https://github.com/marrockx">mariam adekola</a></small
                    >
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the combination of border and width 100% on .content-wrap that's causing the problem. You're effectively making it 100% plus 1 pixel wide.

```
.content-wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.content-wrap {
    
    width: 100%;
}
```

either take off the border or remove width:100% from .content-wrap